# Prove equivalent operator norm characterisation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $f$ is a bounded functional $X\to \mathbb{K}$ and $M=\{x\in X | f(x)=1\}$, I want to prove that $$\|f\|=\frac{1}{\inf_{x\in M} \| x\|}$$

Using $|f(x)|\leq \|f\| \|x\|$, I have proved "$\geq$", but am struggling with the other direction.

Comment: What is the norm you're using in function space?

Comment: $X$ is a normed vector space, there is no specific norm given.

Comment: Don't delete your question immediately after receiving an answer. It's rude to the answerer and unhelpful to other visitors to the site. It also makes it appear as though you are asking questions in bad faith and attempting to hide your tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\inf_{x\in M} \| x\|}&=\sup\Big\{\frac1{\|x\|}:\ x\in M\Big\}
=\sup\Big\{\frac{1}{\|x/f(x)\|}:\ x\ne0,\ f (x)\ne0\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\frac{f (x)}{\|x\|}:\ x\ne0\Big\}=\|f\|.
\end{align}